# Problem with rendering React component in Laravel project

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I have set up React with my Laravel project. In the `resources > js` folder I have an `App.js` and an `index.js`. I also have an `Example.js` file in `resources > js > components` folder. What I am trying to do is to import my `Example.js` into the `App.js`, then import `App.js` into the `index.js` and render it into my blade template. The problem is that it's not showing anything inside of my root div on the page.

Here's the code in my `Example.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';

function Example() {
    return (
        <div>
            TEST
        </div>
    );
}

export default Example;
```

This is the code I have inside `App.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import Example from "./components/Example";

function App() {
    return (
        <Example/>
    )
}

export default App;
```

And this is `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I am using Laravel mix and Webpack, yes

Comment: Ok. Do you include the compiled/built (from the dist folder, `mix.react('resources/js/app.jsx', *'public/js'*);`) script into your page?

Comment: I have this script tag included into my blade template: `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{mix('/js/app.js')}}"></script>`

Comment: Check that your dist js file name is referenced with `{{mix('PATH_TO/YOUR_DIST.js')}}`

Comment: Just make sure that the right file from the webpack build is referenced in your laravel page, check from the mix/webpack config where built files are being placed.